# Trouble Setting Up ANTLR 4 IDE on Eclipse Luna (4.4)

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to install the [ANTLR 4 IDE](https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide) on Eclipse Luna (4.4). I've installed it from the Marketplace but I have no idea how to create a project that has an ANTLR 4 Lexer/Parser in it.

When I go to create a new project I don't see any options for ANTLR 4. I tried creating a .g4 file and it opens in the editor but when I save it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I looked around all over the internet and found a handful of resources that I cobbled together and found a solution by trial and error.
Below is a guide that I've used on a few of my machines to get ANTLR 4 IDE setup in Eclipse. I figured I should share it here and save others the trouble of Google searching for hours (hopefully)

**Prerequisites**

- Eclipse 4.4 Luna Xtext Complete SDK(Needs to be version 2.7.3)
- Eclipse Faceted Project Framework (Tested with 3.4.0) Eclipse Faceted
- Project Framework JDT Enablement(Tested with 3.4.0) ANTLR 4 SDK A
- A copy of the antlr-4.x-complete.jar (4.5 at the time of writing)

**Setup**

1. Install Eclipse

   1. Download it from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
2. Install XText 2.7.3

   1. Go to `Help > Install New Software...`
   2. Enter `http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/` in the `Work With` textbox
   3. Hit Enter and wait for the list to load (this will take a few moments)
   4. Expand the `Xtext` node and check `Xtext Complete SDK` (ensure the version is 2.7.3x)
   5. Click `Next`, agree to the EULA, and click finish
   6. Let the installer finish and restart Eclipse
3. Install Faceted Project Framework

   1. Go to `Help > Install New Software...`
   2. Enter `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna` in the `Work With` textbox
   3. Hit Enter and wait for the list to load (this will take a few moments)
   4. In the filter text box enter `Facet`
   5. Select `Eclipse Faceted Project Framework` and `Eclipse Faceted Project Framework JDT Enablement`
   6. Click `Next`, agree to the EULA, and click finish
   7. Let the installer finish and restart Eclipse
4. Install ANTLR 4 IDE

   1. Go to `Help > Eclipse Marketplace...`
   2. Search for `antlr`
   3. Choose `ANTLR 4 IDE` (make sure it's ANTLR 4 IDE not ANTLR IDE)
   4. Click Install
   5. Let the installer finish clicking ok if it prompts and restart Eclipse
5. Obtain a copy of antlr-4.x-complete.jar

   1. Download the file from [here](http://www.antlr.org/download.html)
   2. Save it somewhere you'll remember

**Creating an ANTRL 4 Project**

I found most of this information [here](https://shijinglu.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/build-antlr4-projects-with-eclipse-java-project-template/), the rest was reading errors and guessing

1. Go to `File > New Project > Project`
2. Expand the `General Tab` and select `ANTLR 4 Project` (if you don't see this see step 4 of setup)
3. Click `Next`, give the project a name and click `Finish`
4. Once the project is complete right click the project and click `Properties`
5. Go to `Project Facets` and click `Convert to faceted form...` (if you don't see this see step 3 of setup)
6. Check the `Java` project facet and click `Apply` (if you don't see this see step 3 of setup)
7. Click `OK`, let the solution rebuild, open the properties again
8. Go to `Java Build Path`, click the `Source` tab
9. Click `Add Folder...` and check `Project > target > generated-sources > antlr4`, click `OK`
10. Click the `Libraries` tab
11. `Add External JARs...`, find your copy of `antlr-4.x-complete.jar`, click `Open`
12. Go to `ANTLR 4 > Tool`, click `Apply` if a pop-up appears
13. Check `Enable project specific settings`
14. Click `Add`, find your copy of `antlr-4.x-complete.jar`, click `Open`
15. Check `4.x`
16. Click `Apply`, click `Yes` to rebuild, click `OK` to exit the properties

**Test**

Create a new class with the following code and try running. In the console write `Hello there` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to send EOF to the input stream

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
public class HelloRunner 
{
    public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream( System.in);

        HelloLexer lexer = new HelloLexer(input);

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        HelloParser parser = new HelloParser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.r(); // begin parsing at rule 'r'
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser)); // print LISP-style tree
    }
}
```

**Notes**

1. If you see an error when you try to go into `ANTLR 4 > Tool` check your Xtext version, 2.8.0 causes an error in the tool window
2. In step 8, if you've changed the directory ANTLR generates it's sources use that directory
3. If you notice that the version of ANTLR you've added to `ANTLR 4 > Tool > Distributions` disappears this seems to be ok

   - Check your build output to see what tool it's using, it should still use the JAR you added even if it disappears. This is what mine looks like:

   `ANTLR Tool v4.5 (C:\JavaLib\antlr-4.5-complete.jar)
   Hello.g4 -o C:\Users\username\workspace\project\target\generated-sources\antlr4 -listener -no-visitor -encoding UTF-8`

Comment: using the newest XText (2.8.2) will not cause an error.

Comment: That's what I read but I'm pretty sure I had 2.8.2 and it caused issues in the settings menu but worked everywhere else

Comment: How can I do the step number 4 on MyEclipse? It does not show any results for search by "antlr". Any repository URL to add?

Comment: @Woland I'm not familiar with MyEclipse. You can download the ANTLR4 IDE directly from it's [repository](https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide)

Comment: I followed these instructions and got Mars/XText 2.7.3/Antler 4.5.2/OSX.  Here are some things I learned: a) XText 2.9.0 and 2.9.2 do not work, b) The setup instructions step 3 for setting up Facets are not necessary as they seem to be installed in Mars, c) On Mac and Linux you use Control-D rather than Control-Z.

Comment: I am using eclipse mars 2 and installing  XText 2.10 helped. Thanks

Comment: I faced some issue with version 2.10, Xtext 2.7.3 is working properly.