# The selected wizard could not be started in eclipse for Anltr 4 .How to solve?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, antlr, antlr4

The selected wizard could not be started.
Failed to create injector for com.github.jknack.antlr4ide.Antlr4 ExtensionFactory: com.github.jknack.antlr4ide.ui.Antlr4ExecutableExtensionFactory
Failed to create injector for com.github.jknack.antlr4ide.Antlr4

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the problem by installing xtext 2.7.3:

1. [Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/modeling/tmf/xtext/downloads/drops/2.7.3/R201411190455/tmf-xtext-Update-2.7.3.zip)
2. In Eclipse > Help > Install New Software...
3. Add... > Archive > Select downloaded .zip file
4. Check **Xtext** from the list > Continue installing
5. Restart eclipse

*Instructions found  [here](https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide/issues/134)  also.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse Mars but this works well with Luna version also.

Make sure that you have Xtext 2.7.3 installed.

1. You can check this by going to Help->Installation Details. Check if you have any other version of Xtext installed. If yes, then please uninstall that.
2. Go to Help->Install New Software , put http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/ in the Work With textbox and hit enter. It will take some time fetching from the server. Click Next, accept license/agreement and then Finish. Your Xtext 2.7.3 is installed.

If still your project is not running you can follow this answer.
[Trouble Setting Up ANTLR 4 IDE on Eclipse Luna (4.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128961/trouble-setting-up-antlr-4-ide-on-eclipse-luna-4-4)

Answer (score 0):

Installed the specific 2.7.3 Xtext version using the downloaded zip and it corrected the issue for me running neon on my mac os x El Capitan