# Why is ANTLR 4 Eclipse plugin generating wrong code?

Tags: eclipse, antlr, antlr4

I'm new to ANTLR, having my first experiments in version 4. Since I use Eclipse Mars, I decided to install the Eclipse ANTLR 4 plugin. After all done, I created the following grammar (`MetaCoder.g4` file):

```
grammar MetaCoder;

init: '{' value (',' value)* '}' ;

value: init
     | INT
     ;

INT: [0-9]+ ;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

The plugin generated to following java code (I removed most the comments to make it shorter):

```
// Generated from MetaCoder.g4 by ANTLR 4.4

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.NotNull;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ErrorNode;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNode;

public class MetaCoderBaseListener implements MetaCoderListener {
    @Override public void enterInit(@NotNull MetaCoderParser.InitContext ctx) { }
    @Override public void exitInit(@NotNull MetaCoderParser.InitContext ctx) { }
    @Override public void enterValue(@NotNull MetaCoderParser.ValueContext ctx) { }
    @Override public void exitValue(@NotNull MetaCoderParser.ValueContext ctx) { }

    @Override public void enterEveryRule(@NotNull ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
    @Override public void exitEveryRule(@NotNull ParserRuleContext ctx) { }
    @Override public void visitTerminal(@NotNull TerminalNode node) { }
    @Override public void visitErrorNode(@NotNull ErrorNode node) { }
}
```

For all the overriden methods Eclipse shows the following error:

```
The method xxx of type MetaCoderBaseListener must override a superclass method
```

The message seems to be correct, since this class does not have an ancestor.

What went wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after posting the question, StackOverflow sugested some related questions and this one has the answer:

[Trouble Setting Up ANTLR 4 IDE on Eclipse Luna (4.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128961/trouble-setting-up-antlr-4-ide-on-eclipse-luna-4-4?rq=1)

The problem, in my case, was that my project was not converted to Facets.

Once I did that the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like ANTLR did not create the `MetaCoderListener` class correctly, defining these methods. When you generate the parser with ANTLR, try to generate it with `-listener` as an argument. This will generate the proper listener, which you class will then implement (The same goes for visitors. Use the `-visitor` argument to generate visitors).